# Javascript : detect real IP address

Tags: javascript, ip

I was using "EasyJQuery" to detect the user's IP address and other information using the script below :

```
<!-- Require jQuery / Anyversion --><script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Require EasyJQuery After JQuery --><script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://api.easyjquery.com/easyjquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    // 1. Your Data Here
    function my_callback(json) {
        alert("IP :" + json.IP + " nCOUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY);
    }

    function my_callback2(json) {
        // more information at http://api.easyjquery.com/test/demo-ip.php
        alert("IP :" + json.IP + " nCOUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY + " City: " + json.cityName + " regionName: " + json.regionName);
    }

    // 2. Setup Callback Function
   // EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback"); // fastest version
    EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback2","full"); // full version
</script>
```

Now it's no more working. The official page is now redirecting to :[ip.codehelper.io](http://ip.codehelper.io/) and the Github library has only a PHP version not a Javascript one.

So is this library really no longer supported? If yes, is there a similar one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the page you linked to:

```
// First, embed this script in your head or at bottom of the page.
<script src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js"></script>
// You can use it
<script>
    alert(codehelper_ip.IP);
    alert(codehelper_ip.Country);
</script>
```

Or something like this might be better:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js&callback=?', function(response) {
    console.log(response.IP, response.Country, response.CityName);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({ 
            url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(location) {
               console.log(location);
              }
        });
```

Comment: please add a brief description of what your block of code is doing to your answer

Comment: Getting a visitor’s location (i.e. city) using JavaScript