# How can i reveal my real IP address using JavaScript/Java/Flash while i'm behind a socks proxy?

Tags: java, javascript, flash, proxy, ip

So i've heard that there are many ways to reveal real IP address of user while he is behind a socks proxy on a website: with JavaSctipt, with Java and with Flash.

I've tried to find some evidence of this in the form of some
[code samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037176/javascript-detect-real-ip-adress/19037435#19037435) and some websites-proxy-checkers like [ip-score.com](http://www.ip-score.com/). I've tested these and some other sites with my socks5 proxy but none of them managed to reveal my real IP.

So i have few questions:

1. What can **really** reveal my IP address? (I've searched for the answer  and opinions differ here)
2. How can i check this working? (Code samples or websites)
3. Is it operating system-dependent? (I've heard that Flash can reveal real IP only under Windows)
4. Is it browser-dependent?